# Jerky rotation in Three.js using Trackball control

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to add a trackball control to the three.js starter [tutorial](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/fundamentals). But after doing that, I found the mouse rotation control to be fairly jerky:

[image: jerky movements]

This only happens to rotation controlled by LMB, RMB pan and MMB zoom are both smooth.

I am suspecting it to be a matter of execution order since the cube seems to roll back in the opposite direction for a frame before rotating in the correct direction.

The code structure is as follows:

```
// Create the trackball control 
const controls = new TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement); 
controls.rotateSpeed = 4;
controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.1;

function render(time) {
    // Something something animation and resolution scale...

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    controls.update();
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Is any part of the code causing the stuttered movement? Or is there something else that is affecting the rotation?